# Python regex to parse groups after specific labels

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of texts like this:

```
Something at the beginning
    
References
1. Ryff, C.D. (2014) Psychological Well-Being Revisited: Advances in the Science and Practice of Eudaimonia. 
2. Deci, E.L. & Ryan, R.M. (2002) Self-determination research: reflections and future directions. 
3. Acedo, F. J., & Casillas, J. C. (2005). Current paradigms in the international management field.
        
Other References
1. Tarelli, E. (2003), “How to transfer responsibilities from expatriates to local nationals”.
2. Riusala, K. and Suutari, V. (2004), “International knowledge transfers through expatriates”.
3. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”.

Something at the end
12. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”.
Something else at the end
```

'Other References' part is present in some texts, but not present in others. Also similar strings could appear anywhere in the texts.

I need regex to use in re.findall and return all strings after 'References' in a list of strings like this.

```
['Ryff, C.D. (2014) Psychological Well-Being Revisited: Advances in the Science and Practice of Eudaimonia.', 'Deci, E.L. & Ryan, R.M. (2002) Self-determination research: reflections and future directions.', 'Acedo, F. J., & Casillas, J. C. (2005). Current paradigms in the international management field.']
```

But ONLY after 'References' and NOT anywhere earlier or later in the text.

I have tried this regex

```
r = 'References\s*(\d+[.].*[.])'
```

But it returns only first string occurrence and I need all

Could anybody please suggest a better regex pattern?

Comment: You can use [`^References$\s*((?:\s*^\d+\.\s*.+$)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/0jgYDp/2).

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thank you. This code returns empty list when applied to the text above.

Comment: I think you forgot to use [`re.M`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M)/[`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) flag ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re.findall`, twice.  The strategy below is to first match all reference blocks as separate strings.  We then join all such strings together, and then use `re.findall` to find all references.

```py
inp = """Something at the beginning

References
1. Ryff, C.D. (2014) Psychological Well-Being Revisited: Advances in the Science and Practice of Eudaimonia. 
2. Deci, E.L. & Ryan, R.M. (2002) Self-determination research: reflections and future directions. 
3. Acedo, F. J., & Casillas, J. C. (2005). Current paradigms in the international management field.
    
Other References
1. Tarelli, E. (2003), “How to transfer responsibilities from expatriates to local nationals”.
2. Riusala, K. and Suutari, V. (2004), “International knowledge transfers through expatriates”.
3. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”.

Something at the end
12. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”.
Something else at the end"""

refs = re.findall(r'^References\n((?:\d+\.\s*.*?\n)+)', inp, flags=re.M)
data = ''.join(refs)
output = re.findall(r'\d+\.\s*(.*?)\n', data)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
[
    'Ryff, C.D. (2014) Psychological Well-Being Revisited: Advances in the Science and Practice of Eudaimonia. ',
    'Deci, E.L. & Ryan, R.M. (2002) Self-determination research: reflections and future directions. ',
    'Acedo, F. J., & Casillas, J. C. (2005). Current paradigms in the international management field.'
]
```

Comment: Thank you, but this code returns references from the 'Other Reference' part and I need to avoid it. I need just references from 'Reference' part

Comment: Reload your page, I have already made that change.

Comment: Also I'd use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) if *References* block appears in text just once. And second `re.findall()` could be replaced with simple list comprehension which iterates over lines ([`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)) and strip ([`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip)) all [*digits*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits), [*whitespaces*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.whitespace) and *dot* (`.`) from each line.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thank you very much, now it works just fine!

Comment: Like this `[s.lstrip(digits + whitespace + ".") for s in data.splitlines()]`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you very much for your care! 
One more thing - sometimes the word 'References' are separated from actual references not by \n, but just by spaces and there are \n inside of reference strings  and references also separated by spaces (bad pdf import)
Could you suggest how to rewrite regex?

I tried re.findall(r'^References\s*?((?:\d+\.\s*.*?[.]?)+)', inp, flags=re.M|re.DOTALL)
but it didn't work.

Comment: You may try using `re.findall(r'^References\s+((?:\d+\.\s*.*?\n)+)', inp, flags=re.M|re.S)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Accepted. 

References are also sometimes separated by spaces and not by \n. Is there any way to rewrite regex ?

Comment: @RostyslavChayka Check my comment just above.  I have given a way to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It still doesn't work in case there is no \n in some texts. I fixed it for r'^References\s+((?:\d+\.\s*.*?\n)+)' because I do know what is the next label.

But have no idea how to fix it in 
output = re.findall(r'\d+\.\s*(.*?)\n', data)

The last \n will not work becouse there are just spaces and no \n

Comment: Please ask a new question, using my answer as a starting point.  Make sure to include the problematical data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for suggestion, done - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73714319/python-regex-to-parse-references-in-specific-format-from-papers

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73714319/python-regex-to-parse-references-in-specific-format-from-papers?noredirect=1&lq=1), which is closed as a duplicate; so I can't answer there.
That duplicate question is more an extension of this question, since it complicates the input.

Using as input example

```
text = """Something at the beginning

References 1. Ryff, C.D. (2014) Psychological Well-Being Revisited: Advances in the Science and Practice of Eudaimonia. Additional Fields. 2. Deci, E.L. & Ryan, R.M. (2002) Self-determination research: reflections and future directions. 3. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”. 315 – 326. DOI: doi.org/10.2224/sbp.2008.36.3.315 4. Acedo, F. J., & Casillas, J. C. (2005). Current paradigms in the international management field. Other References 1. Tarelli, E. (2003), “How to transfer responsibilities from expatriates to local nationals”.
2. Riusala, K. and Suutari, V. (2004), “International knowledge transfers through expatriates”.
3. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”.

Something at the end
12. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”.
Something else at the end"""
```

and working with the following assumptions:

- reference sections are distinguished by the word "References" (with a capital "R"), possibly preceeded by another, capitalized, word (just one word; "Really Bad References" is excluded as a separator for now, though that is straightforward to adjust).
- references in a section are separated by the following:
  one or more digits, followed by a period, followed by a space, followed by non-digit characters (letters, commas, &-signs etc), followed by an opening parenthesis (for the year).
- only the first section, "References", is the one of interest (can probably be straightforwardly amended).

Then the following code can work:

```
# split the sections
pattern = r'[A-Z][a-z\s]+References'
sections = re.split(pattern, text, flags=re.M)

# split the individual references, by conditions as mentioned in point 2 above
pattern = r'\s*(\d+\.\s+\D+\()'
# The first section is blank (`''`), so `sections[1]` is 
# the first actual reference section, "References"
parts = re.split(, sections[1], flags=re.M)

# the split includes the part before the year, and the year + rest. 
# We need to concatenate those items for each reference. 
# Also here, the first group is blank, so skip that
refs = [part1 + part2 for part1, part2 in zip(parts[1::2], parts[2::2])]

# Show the result
for ref in refs:
    print(ref)
```

which yields

```
1. Ryff, C.D. (2014) Psychological Well-Being Revisited: Advances in the Science and Practice of Eudaimonia. Additional Fields.
2. Deci, E.L. & Ryan, R.M. (2002) Self-determination research: reflections and future directions.
3. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”. 315 – 326. DOI: doi.org/10.2224/sbp.2008.36.3.315
4. Acedo, F. J., & Casillas, J. C. (2005). Current paradigms in the international management field.
```