# Python regex to parse references in specific format from papers

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of texts like this:

```
inp = """Something at the beginning

References
1. Ryff, C.D. (2014) Psychological Well-Being Revisited: Advances in the Science and Practice of Eudaimonia. 
2. Deci, E.L. & Ryan, R.M. (2002) Self-determination research: reflections and future directions. 
3. Acedo, F. J., & Casillas, J. C. (2005). Current paradigms in the international management field.
    
Other References
1. Tarelli, E. (2003), “How to transfer responsibilities from expatriates to local nationals”.
2. Riusala, K. and Suutari, V. (2004), “International knowledge transfers through expatriates”.
3. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”.

Something at the end
12. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”.
Something else at the end"""
```

The 'Other References' part is present in some texts, in others, the next part begins with, let's say, 'Good References'. Also, similar strings could appear anywhere in the texts. All reference strings are sometimes separated by '\n', sometimes separated just by spaces. Also, '\n' could occur anywhere in the text, just in the middle of reference strings.

I need regex to use in re.findall and return all strings after 'References' in a list of strings like this:

```
['Ryff, C.D. (2014) Psychological Well-Being Revisited: Advances in the Science and Practice of Eudaimonia.', 'Deci, E.L. & Ryan, R.M. (2002) Self-determination research: reflections and future directions.', 'Acedo, F. J., & Casillas, J. C. (2005). Current paradigms in the international management field.']
```

But ONLY after 'References' and NOT anywhere earlier or later in the text.

I have been suggested to use this regex:

```
refs = re.findall(r'^References\s+((?:\d+\.\s*.*?\n)+)', inp, flags=re.M|re.S)
data = ''.join(refs)
output = re.findall(r'\d+\.\s*(.*?)\n', data)
print(output)
```

But it works only when reference strings are separated by '\n' which is not the case in some texts. And also '\n' could occur anywhere in the texts. I do not need these '\n' at all, so they could be removed from texts.

Example when suggested regex is not working:

```
inp = """Something at the beginning

References 1. Ryff, C.D. (2014) Psychological Well-Being Revisited: Advances in the Science and Practice of Eudaimonia. Additional Fields. 2. Deci, E.L. & Ryan, R.M. (2002) Self-determination research: reflections and future directions. 3. Acedo, F. J., & Casillas, J. C. (2005). Current paradigms in the international management field. Other References 1. Tarelli, E. (2003), “How to transfer responsibilities from expatriates to local nationals”.
2. Riusala, K. and Suutari, V. (2004), “International knowledge transfers through expatriates”.
3. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”.

Something at the end
12. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”.
Something else at the end"""
```

Could anybody please suggest a code that helps me get the list of references?

Comment: Could you maybe add an example string where your pattern doesn't work (but should)?

Comment: Are you saing that sometimes, multiple references are on the same line? I.e., like `1. Ryff, C.D. (2014) Psychological Well-Being Revisited: Advances in the Science and Practice of Eudaimonia.   2. Deci, E.L. & Ryan, R.M. (2002) Self-determination research: reflections and future directions.  3. Acedo, F. J., & Casillas, J. C. (2005). Current paradigms in the international management field.`? What would be the defining characteristic that separates them; the number with the period?

Comment: You already accepted an answer to a very similar, if not identical, [question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73700753/python-regex-to-parse-groups-after-specific-labels?noredirect=1&lq=1). Please be clearer what is the new problem.

Comment: @Rabinzel I have edited question with an example of not working text

Comment: @9769953 yes the problem is when multiple references are on the same line.

I have already accepted the answer when references are separated by '\n' but it appears not to work when it is separated by spaces. Also, I understand that the 'Other references' part could be used as separator.

Comment: I see 3 references before "Other references"; how is "Other references" then a separator between references?

Comment: @9769953 'Other references' separate 'Reference' part which I need to parse from other text below. We couldn't count on any '\n' newlines, it could occur anywhere in the text randomly and reference strings could be separated just by spaces.

Comment: That's not what I mean: there are 3 references, numbered 1. 2. 3., in the "References" part. Are the digit(s) followed by a period the defining separating characteristic for those references?

Comment: @9769953 There are sometimes reference strings like this:
3. Wallace, J. (2001), “The benefits of mentoring for female lawyers”. 315–326. DOI: https://doi.org/10.2224/sbp.2008.36.3.315

So the combination of digit(s) and dot and space could not be a separator. 

Maybe a combination of digit(s), dot, space, authors(with letters, commas, and dots), and year in parentheses could be.

Comment: If there are no digits in the "Something at the" parts `^References\s+(?:\d+\..*)(?:\n(?![^\d\n]*[A-Z][^\d\n]*\n\d+\.).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/XHOiCl/1

Comment: Practically, if you're not sure what separates one reference from another (other than by human intuition), you can only extract the reference sections (References/Good References/Other References/etc); not the internal references.

Comment: I've put an answer to this question at the linked duplicate, since the question closure prevents adding (further) answers here.

Answer (score 0):

> i think  this code may solve ur problem

```
refs = re.findall(r'(?<=References\s)+((?:\d+\.\s*.*?\n)+)[^.\s]*', inp, flags=re.M|re.S)
    data = ''.join(refs)
    output = re.findall(r'\d+\.\s*(.*?)\n', data)
    print(output)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this regex does not separate 'Other references' part when it is separated by spaces, not by '\n'